# Swift 3 parsing API response trouble

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to parse an API response in Swift an Im having trouble getting to nested objects and arrays in the response

here is my sample json

```
{
  "Id": "10",
  "Name": "PV Prediction By Site",
  "Description": "",
  "Permalink": "",
  "Source_format": "JSON",
  "Internal_function_name": "get-meteo-by-site",
  "Additional_parameters": "Prediction",
  "Sites": null,
  "Data": [
    {
      "UTCDateString": "2017-05-01T20:10:33Z",
      "Value": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "name": "Beck_Hill",
            "latitude": 46.26,
            "longitude": -112.44,
            "height": 1926,
            "timezone_abbrevation": "MDT",
            "utc_timeoffset": -6,
            "modelrun_utc": "2017-05-01 12:00",
            "modelrun_updatetime_utc": "2017-05-01 16:41",
            "kwp": 40.26,
            "slope": 30,
            "facing": 180,
            "tracking": 0
          },
          "units": {
            "time": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm",
            "pvpower": "kW",
            "snowcover": "mm",
            "iam": "percent",
            "temperature": "C"
          },
          "data_xmin": {
            "time": [
              "2017-05-01 07:00",
              "2017-05-01 07:15",
              "2017-05-01 07:30",
              "2017-05-01 07:45",
              "2017-05-01 08:00",
              "2017-05-01 08:15",
              "2017-05-01 08:30"
            ],
            "pvpower_instant": [
              40.26,
              40.26,
              40.26,
              40.26,
              40.26
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is some of my parsing code, I can get to the first object in the "Data" array fine, but when i try to get the first object in the Value string it fails to convert the AnyObject to anything else

```
//get a Dictionary of sites
        sitesDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: decodedData, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String:AnyObject]]

        CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (context) in
            //loop thorugh all site and create SiteMO objects from them
            for site in (sitesDictionary?.enumerated())! {
                //SiteMO
                let siteMO = SiteMO.siteInfo(siteInfo: site.element, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
                let siteFeedsDictionary = site.element["Feeds"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                //loop through every feed object and create FeedMO objects from them
                for feed in siteFeedsDictionary.enumerated() {
                    //FeedMO
                    let feedMO = FeedMO.feedInfo(feedInfo: feed.element, site: siteMO, inManagedObjectContext: context)!

                    //what type of data is in the feed?
                    switch feedMO.additionalParameters! {
                    case "Weather":
                        //its a feed with a Weather object
                        print("There should be a WeatherMO created Here")

                    case "Prediction":
                        //its a feed with a Prediction object
                        let dataArray = feed.element["Data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

I need some data out of the "metadata" "units" and "data_xmin" objects

Comment: "Value" is an array and you're trying to parse it as a dictionary

Comment: yes but when i do this let value = feedDataDictionary["Value"]?.firstObject as? [String:AnyObject]

Comment: I get nil when i use the above

Answer (score 0):

For metadata

result[“Data”][0][“Value”][0]

Comment: ["Data"][0] is an Any? and has no member "Value"